# Maven configuration causes error (Eclipse 3.7.1 and Maven 2.2.1)

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a very strange problem with Eclipse (SpringSource Toolsuite 2.8.1 which corresponds to Eclipse 3.7.1 and uses M2Eclipse 1.0) and Maven 2.2.1 :

When I try to import valid projects, which build with no error and no warning using maven command line, Eclipse marks pom.xml as in "error" with error type "Maven Configuration problem".

For the first project, eclipse only says :

```
"org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver"
```

For the other which is a newly created one via simple J2EE archetype, eclipse says : `"org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoResourceCollection"`

What could I do to have more details about these errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling M2Eclipse 1.0 and installing M2Eclipse 0.12 from http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/third-party/m2eclipse-012, the errors have gone.

If someone knows what's wrong about M2Eclipse 1.0 and Maven 2.2.1, he may have a better answer to this problem.

Comment: I've also have this problem with STS 2.9.2 and Maven 3.0.2.